# FIND_IN_SET in MongoDB with CakePHP

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

I am newer in MongoDB with CakePHP. I have following SQL query and I want to convert into mongoDB. I have tried with this syntax `{ field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }` but no luck.

```
$column_name = "football,cricket,vollyboll";
SELECT * FROM CheckBox where FIND_IN_SET("football",$column_name);
```

`$column_name` is database table column which contain value like above mentioned. If more information needed I provide it. Please Help me.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't need special operations for find_in_set, just do `field: some_value` and it will flatten the set and search for that value. Though convert your column from string to array first, make it an actual set

Comment: Can you give mongoDB query which work like `find_in_set`?

Comment: If you column is an array, you can do: `db.c.find({col: 'football'})`

Comment: My column contains `$column_name = "football,cricket,vollyboll";` comma separated value

Comment: Yeah you want to change that to match MongoDB way of doing this. SQL has to do that since it cannot natively represent sets, MongoDB can

Comment: How I can store value in database `columns` ?

Comment: In PHP: `$mongo->collection->insert(array('c' => array('football', 'cricket', 'vollyball')))` as simple as that